# Does MTS User have to be a domain account on Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: tridion

The docs recommend the MTS User is a domain account and installing the Content Manager server software on a machine that is in a Windows domain.

In an external hosting situation where I don't have access to the domain controller and I don't want to keep emailing support to create Windows accounts etc, can I just create the MTS User as a local user on the CM server?

Any gotchas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create the MTSUser account on the local server.  No gotchas or any issues.  Don't forget to NOT add the user to the CMS or the impersonation users account.

Comment: Cheers Rob. When you say "don't forget to not ..." are you saying this is a common mistake or an actual step in the installation documentation that needs to be avoided?

Comment: Adding the MTS Users to your CMS or making it an impersonation account is a common mistake and means you open your system up to security problems. It essentially means you allow modules running as MTSUser to modify content in Tridion without Impersonating.

We see MTSUser being allowed way too often, in part because some error messages actually suggest giving the account those rights to get rid of an authentication failure. It's like saying "the enemy got stopped by your gate. please open the gate to let the enemy in".

Comment: Exactly as Frank mentions - the MTSUser is essential for the Tridion COM+ system (you can see it under the identities tab in Component Services) and this account should only be used for system processes, not scripts or GUI login.

Comment: The MTSUser is already added as a CMS user, only you can't see it. The MTSUser is a privileged user (read: Admin) but is Predefined (read: hidden) so does not appear. 

Indeed do not add the MTSUser to the impersonation users, doing so will open up security.

You only need a domain account for the MTSUser if you indeed to use more than one Tridion server

Comment: Correct answer Robert, but the additional advice should read like this:  Don't forget that your MTSUser is already an admin (as Julian pointed out) so don't let every Tom, Dick and Harry have the login. Don't make your Impersonation Users trustees. Sheesh - being able to adopt the identity of any trustee should be enough power already! It's one of those security-in-depth things. Should impersonation fail for some reason, you don't want the person to suddenly find that hey, guess what, I'm MTSUser! Far better for them to get an authentication failure.

Answer (score 4):

There's no gotchas for a single CM server install, but if you have multiple CM servers connecting to the same DB, each local MTSUser would have to be manually added to the DB with the same settings as the original MTSUser.

For anything beyond a test / dev system, you'd want a domain MTSUser.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the relation between the question and the Thread here, but is a great explanation about why you can't make the MTS User as impersonation user.

Those answers are good but the context of the answers are regardless if the user is a domain one or a local one.

If the question is if you can have the MTSUser as a local account the answer is yes.

If the question is if that is a good practice, the answer is no, as doesn't help in the maintenance of the platform, 
specially in an enterprise environment because maintenance reasons, business process reasons.

However in the context of the scenario where the question is asked and if takes days to make any change at the domain level
maybe could make sense to use a local account, but don't add the user to the CMS nor add as an impersonation one :)

Comment: may we convince you to committing to the Tridion SE site, your help there will be appreciated http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2